# Image upload API error for multipart/form-data in my angular10 application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am developing an angular10 application with the image upload function, but when I trying to upload I am receiving the error "422 Unprocessable Entity".

Here is the code for my component.ts

```
multiImageUpload = (event) => {
    const files = event.target.files;
    let isImage = true;

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (files.item(i).type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      } else {
        isImage = false;
        alert('invalid format!');
        break;
      }
    }

    if (isImage) {
      this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    } else {
      this.selectedFiles = undefined;
      event.srcElement.percentage = null;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; i++) {
      this.upload(i, this.selectedFiles[i]);
    }
  }

  upload = (i, file) => {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);
    formData.append('filename', file.name);

    this.uploadService.imageUpload(formData).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('image upload success', res);
    });
  }
```

Here is the upload.service.ts

```
imageUpload = (formData: FormData) => {
    return this.crud.uploadImage(formData, '/uploadfile');
  };
```

Here is the crud.service.ts code:

```
// image upload
  uploadImage(data: any, ...parameters): Observable<any> {
    const API = `${this.apiUrl}` + parameters.join('/');
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    return this.http
      .post(API, data, {
        headers: httpHeaders,
      })
      .pipe(catchError(this.error));
  }
```

Here attached backend code screenshot
[image]

Here is the API response screenshot
[image]

[image]
[image]

Please help me out with this problem. I have tried some other ways also but the API error persists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution!

Existing code:

```
upload = (i, file) => {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);
    formData.append('filename', file.name);

    this.uploadService.imageUpload(formData).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('image upload success', res);
    });
  }
```

working code:

```
upload = (i, file) => {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('filename', file, file.name);

    this.uploadService.imageUpload(formData).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('image upload success', res);
    });
  }
```

I just changed the formData.append 2 lines to one line
`formData.append('filename', file, file.name);`

Thank you all.